# Questions with passive voice

Tags: passive, question

Consider translating this question:

> Whom is she dependent on?

My try would be:

> Wem ist sie abhängig von?

Unfortunately, my grammar book doesn’t cover questions with passive and examples from Google searches only show examples of *using* the passive voice – not questioning with it.

Or should I completely rephrase it, something like:

> Wem ist (the subject), von (...) sie abhängig ist?

Comment: Note that your English sentence is not in the passive voice. It only has a somewhat unusual (but AFAIK correct) word order.

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't say it's passive voice, because "abhängig" is an adjective. What you are after is:

> Von wem ist sie abhängig?

in case you are sure the object she depends on is a person.

A variant is

> Wovon ist sie abhängig?

in case the answer might not be a person.

A rule of thumb for verbs with prepositions like "abhängen von", "sich beschäftigen mit" and hundreds of them, would be to formulate the question by concatenating

> `Wo`+`preposition` `verb` `subject` and so on. ?